# How to intercept the creation of an entity in strapi?

Tags: javascript, strapi

I know that under the `src/api` folder are the entity folders each allowing 4 folders *content-types*, *controllers*, *routes*, and *services*. If I want to extend or change the behavior of an API then I intervene in the file under the controllers folder, possibly services as well. But this is only good for external calls.

For example if I want to do it when I use an external API I do the following under the foder `/controllers` => `my-entity-name.js`:

```
"use strict";

/**
 *  my-entity-name controller
 */

const { createCoreController } = require("@strapi/strapi").factories;

module.exports = createCoreController("api::my-entity-name.my-entity-name", ({ strapi }) => ({
  async create(ctx) {
    //Do my stuff here
    //create manually the entity or super.create(ctx)
  }
}))
```

I need to intercept the creation of an entity when the latter is done from the backoffice. Basically I need to invoke an external service before creating it. I noticed that it does not go through the same endpoint as the external API but it uses an internal one made like this: `/content-manager/collection-types/api::my-entity.my-entity`

What should I do to intercept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to do model lifecycle:

`src/api/contenType/models/contentType/lifecycles.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  async beforeCreate(event) {
     …
  }
}
```

If you need to stop creation due to error you can `throw new ApplicationError(‘message’)`

[reference](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/error-handling.html#services-and-models-lifecycles)